# My attempt to optimize memset on a 64bit machine takes more time than standard implementation. Can someone please explain why?

Tags: c, 64-bit, memset

(machine is x86 64 bit running SL6)

I was trying to see if I can optimize memset on my 64 bit machine. As per my understanding memset goes byte by byte and sets the value. I assumed that if I do in units of 64 bits, it would be faster. But somehow it takes more time. Can someone take a look at my code and suggest why ?

```
/* Code */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void memset8(unsigned char *dest, unsigned char val, uint32_t count)
{
    while (count--)
        *dest++ = val;
}
void memset32(uint32_t *dest, uint32_t val, uint32_t count)
{
    while (count--)
        *dest++ = val;
}
void
memset64(uint64_t *dest, uint64_t val, uint32_t count)
{
    while (count--)
        *dest++ = val;
}
#define CYCLES 1000000000
int main()
{
    clock_t start, end;
    double total;
    uint64_t loop;
    uint64_t val;

    /* memset 32 */
    start = clock();
    for (loop = 0; loop < CYCLES; loop++) {
        val = 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF;
        memset32((uint32_t*)&val, 0, 2);
    }
    end = clock();
    total = (double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Timetaken memset32 %g\n", total);

    /* memset 64 */
    start = clock();
    for (loop = 0; loop < CYCLES; loop++) {
        val = 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF;
        memset64(&val, 0, 1);
    }
    end = clock();
    total = (double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Timetaken memset64 %g\n", total);

    /* memset 8 */
    start = clock();
    for (loop = 0; loop < CYCLES; loop++) {
        val = 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF;
        memset8((unsigned char*)&val, 0, 8);
    }
    end = clock();
    total = (double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Timetaken memset8 %g\n", total);

    /* memset */
    start = clock();
    for (loop = 0; loop < CYCLES; loop++) {
        val = 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF;
        memset(&val, 0, 8);
    }
    end = clock();
    total = (double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Timetaken memset %g\n", total);

    printf("-----------------------------------------\n");
}

/*Result*/
Timetaken memset32 12.46
Timetaken memset64 7.57
Timetaken memset8 37.12
Timetaken memset 6.03
-----------------------------------------
```

Looks like the standard memset is more optimized than my implementation. 
I tried looking into code and everywhere is see that implementation of memset is same as what I did for memset8. When I use memset8, the results are more like what I expect and very different from memset. 
Can someone suggest what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: memset will use sse2, sse4 and avx instruction when available. Don't be a fool and use the standard implementation :)

Comment: You could always get your compiler to spit out assembly and compare the differences between your implementations and the stdlib one. Also, 37s seems like an awfully long time to execute your `memset8` test case; are you compiling with optimizations turned on?

Comment: look at [this implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/string.subproj/memset.c)... this is almost the memset64 implementation...

Comment: @V-X: that’s an ancient reference implementation.  The implementation that is actually in use on OSX and iOS is quite thoroughly different (and written in assembly).

Comment: aside from what others have said, you're spending a lot of time counting the for loop, not load/stores. You should fill a large array and see the result

Comment: @sehe, the standard implementation is not necessarily optimized.  Agner Fog has his [asmlib](http://www.agner.org/optimize/asmlib.zip) which contains several assembly optimized functions including memset.  See the documentation (and asm code).  He has a nice table comparing memset (acutally memcpy) with MSVC, Mac, GNU... The GNU version was clearly not very optimized while the Mac version was compared to his code.

Comment: @Zboson be-that-as-it-may it still doesn't make rewriting the algorithms in straight C/C++ very worthwhile. Unless for learning.

Comment: @sehe, I agree, it's only useful for learning.  It's not worthwhile writing a general memset function in C but it's probably worth trying some special cases for learning especially if you can get a better result than the standard implementation.

Answer (score 10):

Actual `memset` implementations are typically hand-optimized in assembly, and use the widest aligned writes available on the targeted hardware.  On x86_64 that will be at least 16B stores (`movaps`, for example).  It may also take advantage of prefetching (this is less common recently, as most architectures have good automatic streaming prefetchers for regular access patterns), streaming stores or dedicated instructions (historically `rep stos` was unusably slow on x86, but it is quite fast on recent microarchitectures).  Your implementation does none of these things.  It should not be terribly surprising that the system implementation is faster.

As an example, consider the [implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.40.1/x86_64/string/memset.s) used in OS X 10.8 (which has been superseded in 10.9).  Here’s the core loop for modest-sized buffers:

```
.align 4,0x90
1:  movdqa %xmm0,   (%rdi,%rcx)
    movdqa %xmm0, 16(%rdi,%rcx)
    movdqa %xmm0, 32(%rdi,%rcx)
    movdqa %xmm0, 48(%rdi,%rcx)
    addq   $64,      %rcx
    jne    1b
```

This loop will saturate the LSU when hitting cache on pre-Haswell microarchitectures at 16B/cycle.  An implementation based on 64-bit stores like your `memset64` cannot exceed 8B/cycle (and may not even achieve that, depending on the microarchitecture in question and whether or not the compiler unrolls your loop).  On Haswell, an implementation that uses AVX stores or `rep stos` can go even faster and achieve 32B/cycle.

Answer (score 3):

> As per my understanding memset goes byte by byte and sets the value.

The details of what the `memset` facility does are implementation dependent.  Relying on this is usually a good thing, because the I'm sure the implementors have extensive knowledge of the system and know all kind of techniques to make things as fast as possible.

To elaborate a little more, lets look at:

```
memset(&val, 0, 8);
```

When the compiler sees this it can notice a few things like:

- The fill value is 0
- The number of bytes to fill is 8

and then choose the right instructions to use depending on where `val` or `&val` is (in a register, in memory, ...).  But if `memset` is stuck needing to be a function call (like your implementations), none of those optimizations are possible.  Even if it can't make compile time decisions like:

```
memset(&val, x, y); // no way to tell at compile time what x and y will be...
```

you can be assured that there's a function call written in assembler that will be as fast as possible for your platform.

Comment: I am using linux and glibc with gcc compiler. This should be open source and standard. Isn't it ?

Comment: Can you suggest a faster way of doing it?

Comment: `memset` *behaves* as if it were byte-by-byte. But all competent compilers today treat it as a built-in internal and will often use SSE or AVX instructions.

Comment: @adikshit,  `memset` isn't necessarily a function call, and seems to work (at least for the x86/x86_64 instruction set), much as Mysticial describes (at least the last time I looked at it).

Comment: I'm not sure it's good to assume that each compilers built in internal is optimized.  If you see Agner Fog's manuals he recommends turning off GCC's built in internal functions `-fno-builtin`.  The memcpy and memset functions were not optimized when he tested him.  He has hand optimized several functions in assembly  [asmlib](http://www.agner.org/optimize/asmlib.zip) and his version memset was clearly much faster at the time (though the Mac version performed well).  Maybe GCC has improved since then...

Comment: @Zboson, these days it will be optimized, relative to what you can write _in C_.  It's an open question if the internal is optimized relative to another piece of assembly.

Comment: @Idav1s, prove it.  I know the GCC math libraries are not so good.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth exploring how to write a faster memset particularly with GCC (which I assume you are using with Scientific Linux 6) in C/C++.  Many people assume the standard implementation is optimized.  **This is not necessarily true.**  If you see table 2.1 of Agner Fog's [Optimizing Software in C++](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) manuals he compares memcpy for for several different compilers and platforms to his own assembly optimized version of memcpy.  Memcpy in GCC at the time really underperformed (but the Mac version was good).  He claims the built in functions are even worse and recommends using `-no-builtin`.  GCC in my experience is very good at optimizing code but its library functions (and built in functions) are not very optimized (with ICC it's the other way around).

It would be interesting to see how good you could do using intrinsics. If you look at his [asmlib](http://www.agner.org/optimize/asmlib.zip) you can see how he implements `memset` with SSE and AVX (it would be interesting to compare this to the Apple's optimized version Stephen Canon posted).

With AVX you can see he writes 32 bytes at a time.

```
K100: ; Loop through 32-bytes blocks. Register use is swapped
      ; Rcount = end of 32-bytes blocks part
      ; Rdest = negative index from the end, counting up to zero
      vmovaps [Rcount+Rdest], ymm0
      add     Rdest, 20H
      jnz     K100
```

vmovaps in this case is the same as the intrinsic `_mm256_store_ps`.  Maybe GCC has improved since then but you might be able to beat GCC's implementation of `memset` using intrinsics.  If you don't have AVX you certainly have SSE (all x86 64bit do) so you could look at the SSE version of his code to see what you could do.

Here is a start for your memset32 funcion assuming the array fits in the L1 cache.  If the array does not fit in the cache you want to do a non temporal store with `_mm256_stream_ps`.  For a general function you need several cases also including cases when the memory is not 32 byte aligned.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
int main() {

    int count = (1<<14)/sizeof(int);
    int* dest = (int*)_mm_malloc(sizeof(int)*count, 32); // 32 byte aligned

    int val = 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF;
    __m256 val8 = _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_set1_epi32(val));
    for(int i=0; i<count; i+=8) {
        _mm256_store_ps((float*)(dest+i), val8);
    }
}
```